# How to prevent overflow in MLE method for large data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, scipy-optimize

I am trying to do a manual MLE estimation using scipy. My dataset is not that large so it surprises me that my values get very large very fast and scipy.optimize.minimize seems to get into NaNs for my density extremely quickly. I've tried to use the sum of logarithms instead of the product of the densities but that did not make things better at all.

This is my data:

```
[
        1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.004, 1.005, 1.008, 1.014, 1.015, 1.023, 1.035, 1.038,
        1.046, 1.048, 1.050, 1.050, 1.052, 1.052, 1.057, 1.063, 1.070, 1.070, 1.076,
        1.087, 1.090, 1.091, 1.096, 1.101, 1.102, 1.113, 1.114, 1.120, 1.130, 1.131,
        1.150, 1.152, 1.154, 1.155, 1.162, 1.170, 1.177, 1.189, 1.191, 1.193, 1.200,
        1.200, 1.200, 1.200, 1.205, 1.210, 1.218, 1.238, 1.238, 1.241, 1.250, 1.250,
        1.256, 1.257, 1.272, 1.278, 1.289, 1.299, 1.300, 1.316, 1.331, 1.349, 1.374,
        1.378, 1.382, 1.396, 1.426, 1.429, 1.439, 1.443, 1.446, 1.473, 1.475, 1.478,
        1.499, 1.506, 1.559, 1.568, 1.594, 1.609, 1.626, 1.649, 1.650, 1.669, 1.675,
        1.687, 1.715, 1.720, 1.735, 1.750, 1.755, 1.787, 1.797, 1.805, 1.898, 1.908,
        1.940, 1.989, 2.010, 2.012, 2.024, 2.047, 2.081, 2.085, 2.097, 2.136, 2.178,
        2.181, 2.193, 2.200, 2.220, 2.301, 2.354, 2.359, 2.382, 2.409, 2.418, 2.430,
        2.477, 2.500, 2.534, 2.572, 2.588, 2.591, 2.599, 2.660, 2.700, 2.700, 2.744,
        2.845, 2.911, 2.952, 3.006, 3.021, 3.048, 3.059, 3.092, 3.152, 3.276, 3.289,
        3.440, 3.447, 3.498, 3.705, 3.870, 3.896, 3.969, 4.000, 4.009, 4.196, 4.202,
        4.311, 4.467, 4.490, 4.601, 4.697, 5.100, 5.120, 5.136, 5.141, 5.165, 5.260,
        5.329, 5.778, 5.794, 6.285, 6.460, 6.917, 7.295, 7.701, 8.032, 8.142, 8.864,
        9.263, 9.359, 10.801, 11.037, 11.504, 11.933, 11.998, 12.000, 14.153, 15.000,
        15.398, 19.793, 23.150, 27.769, 28.288, 34.325, 42.691, 62.037, 77.839
]
```

How can I perform the MLE algorithm without running into overlow issues?

In case you are wondering, I am trying to fit the function `f(x) = alpha * 500000^(alpha) / x^(alpha+1)`. So what I have is

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# data = the given dataset
log_pareto_pdf = lambda alpha, x: np.log(alpha * (5e5 ** alpha) / (x ** (alpha + 1)))
ret = minimize(lambda alpha: -np.sum([log_pareto_pdf(alpha, x) for x in data]), x0=np.array([1]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to avoid the giant exponentiations. One way to do this is to actually simplify your function:

```
log_pareto_pdf = lambda alpha, x: np.log(alpha) + alpha*np.log(5e5) - (alpha + 1)*np.log(x)
```

Without simplifying, your program still needs to try to calculate the `5e5**alpha` term, which will get really big really fast (overflow around 55).

You'll also need to supply the `bounds` argument to `minimize` to prevent any negatives inside the `log`'s.

Comment: You might also consider using [`minimize_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html) since you're minimizing a scalar function of one variable

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you! In hindsight, getting rid of the exponentiation seems kinda obvious. I was hoping more along the lines of just choosing a much larger data type but I guess that is neither how it works, nor how it should work.